# How to achieve "fall off the bone" in a leg of lamb using sous vide?

Tags: temperature, sous-vide, lamb

I have recently experimented with leg of lamb, following the popular recipe on [chefsteps](https://www.chefsteps.com/activities/mastering-leg-of-lamb-a-stress-free-technique-for-a-stunning-feast) . Both times I cooked the meat, with bone, for 24h at 57°C (134°F).

While the result was generally good, I received a comment, that the meat didn't fall of the bone, and that perhaps next time, I should increase the temperature. However, I think, that I need to increase the time instead.

What is the solution for this situation? Is it even possible to achieve fall of the bone, cooking at low temperatures?

I have read, that for the fall of the bone effect to occur, connective tissue must break up, which happens at 145°F (62°C), which is obviously quite a bit more temperature, than my setup.

For the record, the meat was quite tender, but it had structure, it was not mushy and it also didn't fall of the bone.

Comment: Relevant, perhaps a duplicate: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/86511/time-and-temperature-for-converting-collagen-to-gelatin-in-chuck-roast-cooked-so

Comment: Lamb falling off the bone? What a waste..
To me, it should be pink, and yes, have texture.

Comment: Meat "falling off the bone" is overcooked unless you're going to be pulling/shredding it, and I don't think I've ever made anything of that consistency in a sous vide. Sous vide meat in my experience is firm yet tender, not separating.

Comment: I’m guessing the aim is for something like braised lamb shank?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ribs and legs are "done" when they are 145°F internal temp, but they may still be tough. If you take them up to 190 to 203°F, the collagens and fats melt at this temp and make the meat more tender and juicy.

Alot of people prefer caramelized and easy to eat meat. Altough I would not call this sous vide.

A longer cooking time would not melt the fats and collagens, but tenderize the meat more.